# XGBoost features with more feature importance giving less accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have six features for my model `f1,f2,f3,f4,f5 and f6`.
And feature importance scores are in order

```
f1>f2>f3>f4>f5>f6
```

but rmse of model with features `f1,f4 and f5` is less than rmse of model with features `f1,f2,f3,f4,f5 and f6` or model with features `f1,f2,f3`. Any possible reason for this?

Comment: your question is little bit harder to understand than necessary as you are switching between accuracy and rmse

Comment: @CAFEBABE sorry that was a typo, I dont know how I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to guess without the data.
However, typically this results from correlated features.
So if `f2==f1` it would be the case that adding `f2` to a model which contains already `f1` does not provide any value. However, adding an uncorrelated feature, e.g. `f4` can add a lot even so `f2 > f1`

Comment: Okay so these is not any rule or reason for why adding all the features increase rmse, it depends on the data.